# Click on a href

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a autologin script. I already did the first steps, go to the web, fill the username and password and press a button.

Now I need to go to another pages, that page have a href code and I don't know how or what I need to put to go to this href

Im trying with this

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@href='Consulta de Medidas']").click()
```

Here the code from the web:

```
<a href="/consulta-de-medidas/">Consulta de Medidas</a>
```

But it is not working

Anyone could help me??

Comment: `browser.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Consulta de Medidas'])[1]/following::nav[1]").click()` try it generated by katalon

Comment: Your href is `'/consulta-de-medidas/'`not `'Consulta de Medidas'`

Comment: python show me this message : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rogarui/Desktop/Python/facturas_green.py", line 23, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Consulta de Medidas'])[1]/following::nav[1]").click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the following solutions:

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_link_text("Consulta de Medidas").click()
  ```
- Using `selector`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='consulta-de-medidas']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/consulta-de-medidas/' and contains(.,'Consulta de Medidas')]").click()
  ```

---

### Update

Possibly you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Consulta de Medidas"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='consulta-de-medidas']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/consulta-de-medidas/' and contains(.,'Consulta de Medidas')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: python shows me this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rogarui/Desktop/Python/facturas_green.py", line 23, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/consulta-de-medidas/' and contains(.,'Consulta de Medidas')]").click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

Comment: @rogarui Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: firs thanks for your help                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rogarui/Desktop/Python/facturas_green.py", line 23, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/consulta-de-medidas/' and contains(.,'Consulta de Medidas')]"))).click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @rogarui _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.